# Any effective solver to solve selection problem with constraints

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am working on a package selection problem. I have to put a constraint on the final result, like ‘top3 brands among selected products should account for less than 50%’.

I try to implement that on Pulp. But it seems CBC solver do not support such constraint. Please help me. How can I put such constraint? Or should I switch to another solver?

Comment: "Solver selection problem"?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on what exactly "top 3 brands" is. If you mean the sum of the three largest `x[i]` should be less than 50% of the total, then this can be linearized as follows:

```
    y1 >= x[i]              for all i
    y2 >= x[i]-M*delta1[i]  for all i
    y3 >= x[i]-M*delta2[i]  for all i
    y1+y2+y3 <= sum(i,x[i])/2
    sum(i, delta1[i]) = 1
    sum(i, delta2[i]) = 2
    delta1[i],delta2[i] ∈ {0,1}
```

This can be solved with CBC. Here `M` is a large enough constant (called `big-M`) and `delta1`,`delta2` are binary variables. Note that y1,y2,y3 are bounds on the largest three values, so interpreting these values may not always be obvious. Basically, the definition of these values is:

```
  y1 : variable at least as large as the largest x[i]
  y2 : variable at least as large as the second largest x[i]
  y3 : variable at least as large as the third largest x[i]
```

Other and better formulations exist (but this one is a bit more intuitive [for me that is]).

A simpler approach would be to use `sum_largest(x,k)` in CVXPY, e.g.

```
  sum_largest(x,3) <= sum(x)/2
```

Comment: “Top3” means: the top3 brands with largest quantity in selected package. Eg. there are 1000 items. Each belongs to a certain brand. We will select some items and top3 brands should account for less than 50%(in the final combination). I am not an expert in linear programming. I guess it is not a MILP problem? And could u give more detailed explanation on your code? I am confused with the meaning of delta and M. Tks a lot!

Comment: Tks for ur answer. BTW can u give a brief introduction why y2 denotes “at least as large as the second largest x[i]”. For me, the inequalities above are equivalent to ‘x[i] <= 50%/3’